# How to Find two specific conditions in a two-dimensional list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I'm using the acceptance resnet v2 model to infer images.

A label deduced about the input image and a score on how accurate it is to make a two-dimensional array. By the way, can you find a factor that satisfies both conditions?

For example

```
list_total = [('cheese cake', '0.99597'), ('cheese soup', '0.00114'), ('cheese candy', '0.00102'), ('red cake', '0.00098'), ('red soup', '0.00039'), ('red candy', '0.00029'), ('blue cake', '0.00019'), ('blue soup', '0.00001'), ('blue candy', '0.00001')]
```

In the list above, I would like to find an element that contains 'cheese' and has a number greater than 0.90000

```
image_path = sys.argv[1]
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()


label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
               in tf.gfile.GFile("my_labels.txt")]


with tf.gfile.FastGFile("my.proto", 'rb') as f:

graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
_ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('InceptionResnetV2/Logits/Predictions:0')
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
                           {'input_image:0': image_data})

    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    list_total = []
    for node_id in top_k :
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        human_score = '%.5f'%(score)
        hair_total.append((human_string,human_score))

    for item in hair_total :

        if 'cheese' in item[0] :
            print('yes')
        else :
            print ('no')
```

When you run the code above, you say yes to the list that contains the 'cheese'

```
yes
yes
yes
no
no
no
no
no
no
```

but how do you find the one that contains the 'cheese' and has the largest number? like this

```
yes
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can find first item that match your conditions using list comprehension.

`print(next(i for i in list_total if 'cheese' in i[0] and float(i[1]) > .9))`

---

If you want items whose second value is the highest you could use [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with `key` argument equal to function that will point to second value of your elements and convert them to `float` type.

`print(max([i for i in list_total if 'cheese' in i[0]], key=lambda x: float(x[1])))`

**Output:**

`('cheese cake', '0.99597')`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late to say thank you.
Thanks to you, I've been very helpful!

Comment: Glad to have been for help :)